# Angular custom error handler is not always hit after errors

Tags: angular, error-handling, observable, interceptor

I have an app where I use ngXS, an auth interceptor and global error handler as well. I have a login action and another action where I get some entities from the server. Auth interceptor is working fine,  but I want to use the error handler in case of every error of course.
In the interceptor, the errors are catched and thrown, but the error of the get action does not appear in the blobal error handler, the login action does, they are the same type of HttpErrorResponse...

Code:

```
get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.backendUrl}get`, this.httpOptions);
}

login(email: string, password: string) {
    const param = JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password });
    return this.http.post(`${this.backendUrl}login`, param, this.httpOptions);
}
```

AuthState:

```
@Action(Login)
login({ patchState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, { payload }: Login) {
    return this.authService.login(payload.userName, payload.password)
      .pipe(tap((result: { jwtBearerToken: string, email: string, expiresIn: number, userId: number }) => {
        patchState({ token: result.jwtBearerToken, userName: result.email, expiresIn: result.expiresIn, userId: result.userId });
        this.store.dispatch(new Navigate(['/list']));
      }))
}
```

ThingsState:

```
@Action(Fetch)
getThings({ getState, setState }: StateContext<ThingsStateModel>) {
    const state = getState();

    this.service.get().subscribe(getResult => {
        setState({
        ...state,
        things: getResult
        });
    });
}
```

AuthInterceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private store: Store) {}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>,
          next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.store.selectSnapshot(AuthState.token);
    let request: HttpRequest<any> = req;

    if (token) {
        request = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set("Authorization",
                "Bearer " + token)
        });
    }

    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(catchError((error, caught) => {
            // !!  this throw is executed in both cases !!
            throw error;
            return of(error);
        }) as any);
    }
}
```

Global error handler:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    handleError(error: Error) {
    //  this is hit only in the case of errors during the Login action...
    }
}
```

Any ideas what to try? Thanks!

Comment: try this  `return of(error);` =>  `return throwError(error);`

Comment: No difference at all unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is just a typo.

In your get() function, you are using "this.httpClient". But, in your login() function, you are using "this.http".

Also in your ThingsState, you can add a catchError() and dispatch a different action like so.

```
@Action(Fetch)
getThings({ getState, setState }: StateContext<ThingsStateModel>) {
    const state = getState();

    this.service.get()
    .pipe(
      map(result => {
        setState({...state, things: result})
      }),
      catchError(() => dispatch(resetThings()))
    );
}

@Action(ResetThings)
resetThings({patchState}: StateContext<ThingsStateModel>) {
  // Reset your model or handle the error
}
```